# Update existing migration in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I created a Migration to insert values to the table like:

```
public partial class Agreement : Migration
{
    protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {
        migrationBuilder.InsertData(
           schema: "dbo",
           table: "user",
           columns: new[] { "id", "description", "name"},
           values: new object[] { 69,"agreement-accept","accept" });

        migrationBuilder.InsertData(
          schema: "dbo",
          table: "link_role_permission",
          columns: new[] { "role_id", "permission_id"},
          values: new object[] {8,79 });
    }

    protected override void Down(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {

    }
  }
 }
```

I want to change the "description" value to something else. How I can do that?

1. Can I update existing migration?
2. If I need to delete and add a new migration, how I can delete specific migration? (This is not the last migration).

I tried these for deleting none are working for delete migration:

Agreement is the name of the class, 20220826185818_Agreement" is the name of the migration file.

```
   Remove-Migration "20220826185818_Agreement" -Force
   Remove-Migration "Agreement" -Force"

   Remove-Migration 20220826185818_Agreement  -Force
   Remove-Migration Agreement -Force
```

Comment: If you ran it already and there's a record in the migration history table, I would just create a new migration with the change so when you update other environments it doesn't cause any issues.

Answer (score 0):

You should add a new migration to make that change. I don't think it is a good idea to update the existing migration.

Modifying migration should be done only when you are creating a new migration and you're sure no one has applied it to database.

If you don't like such mess in the old migrations, consider squashing them. [Microsoft documentation here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/managing?tabs=dotnet-core-cli#resetting-all-migrations) has the steps. Carefully do it if you have had customized migration code, which is something like stuff explained in [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/managing?tabs=dotnet-core-cli#customize-migration-code).